# remote LPD on port 516

Tags: printing, lpr

Some colleges have setup an Infoprint LPD printer on a remote host.
Because of another print system using port 515 on this remote server, 
they have setup the Infoprint LPD on port 516.

Normally I use the command below to setup a remote printer/queue on AIX,
but I can't find anything about changing the default LPR/LPD port.

```
/usr/lib/lpd/pio/etc/piomisc_ext mkpq_remote_ext -q 'local_q' -h 'host' -r 'remote_q' -t 'bsd' -C 'FALSE' -d 'description'
```

Do any of you know how to set it up for another port than 515?

Thanks in advance
Claus

Comment: Tried option `-p 516` yet?

Comment: YES!
mkpq_remote_ext[10]: getopts: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.

Comment: My second guess:`-P 516` with upper-case 'p'

Comment: I will try, but none of documentation mentions that.

Comment: Okay! It didn't return any errors. :-)
I have to wait for network to open firewall, and then I'll come back with the result.
Thank you so far.

Comment: well -P don't give an error, but isn't working.
I asked IBM, and it kan only be done by changing 515 -> 516 in /etc/services.
This will also change the local lpd printers :-(

Comment: Oh well, that's right, checked the script in question, it does have an `-P` option, but that does something else (also it takes a TRUE|FALSE value, not a number) -- Perhaps you could run a port forwarder (eg rinetd) on another computer...